# Does Open API 3.0 support different generations for frontend and backend?

Tags: rest, openapi, openapi-generator

Can anyone help me with the following confusion regarding the Open API 3.0 specification.

Say I want to specify an endpoint for a sign-up use case.

```
POST /signup
```

The endpoint (on the frontend side) should accepts a requestBody with following parameters (in JSON format):

```json
    {
    "email": "user@user.com",
    "password": "blaa",
    "passwordConfirm": "blaa"
    }
```

The endpoint (on the backend side) should return a repsonse looks like this:

```json
    {
    "email": "user@user.com",
    "password": "blaa",
    "passwordConfirm": "blaa",
    "handle": "username",
    "createdAt": "2021-05-28T12:39:47.802Z"
    }
```

There should be two more fields in the response that needs to be set in the backend (`createdAt` and `handle`)

My goal is to generate the frontend and backend which should output different code:

- frontend: email, password, passwordConfirm
- backend: email, password, passwordConfirm, handle, createdAt

Is this something I can specify with Open API 3.0?
How would the specification look like?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a field named as `readOnly` If it's set to true means that the particular parameter may be sent as part of a response but should not be sent as part of the request.

You can check `Read-Only and Write-Only Properties` section in the [specification](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/).

For example, in your case it would look like:

```yaml
    type: object
    properties:
      email:
        type: string
      password:
        type: string
      passwordConfirm:
        type: string
      handle:
        type: string
        readOnly: true
      createdAt:
        type: string
        readOnly: true
```